# Javascript function to determine if number any combination of numbers in array add up to max value

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

For example: if arr contains [4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3] the output should return true because 4 + 6 + 10 + 3 = 23. The array will not be empty, will not contain all the same elements, and may contain negative numbers. 
My Attempt 
Uses a recursive method to find all permutations of the arr and adds elements up to see if they add up to array max. The function checks all permutations correctly but does not return correct boolean.

```
function arrayAddition(arr) {
    var arrMax = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
                     return a - b;
                 }).pop();

    function recArrAdd(sub, arr) {

        if (arr.length > 0) {
            var arrSum = sub.concat(arr[0]).reduce(function(prev, curr) {
                return prev + curr;
            });

            if (arrSum === arrMax) return true;
            recArrAdd(sub.concat(arr[0]), arr.slice(1));
            recArrAdd(sub, arr.slice(1));
        }
        return false;
    }

    return recArrAdd([], arr);
}

console.log(arrayAddition([1, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: @maioman there's a `.reduce()` call in the function posted!

Comment: Any restrictions on values?

Comment: Can you please check this link.. Similar problem http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36214/find-all-subsets-of-an-int-array-whose-sums-equal-a-given-target

Comment: That is a related problem, @SanketBajoria, and I added an answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the problem lies in the `if (arrSum === arrMax) return true;` check. At some points in the execution of the program `arrSum` is actually equal to the respective `arr[0]`. But when `arr[0]` happens to be the *MAX* element in your array then you get a false positive.

So, you have to incorporate another check : `if (arr[0] != arrMax)`

Also, your function should not return *false* when the `if (arr.length > 0)` check fails. Instead you can use a global flag variable (`found` as seen in the code below) and return this as the final outcome.

---

**EDIT:** Also, the check `if (found) return true;` is placed right at the top of `recArrAdd()` for performance reasons: It helps avoid unnecessary further calls, since when `found` is `true` the job is done.

For example, *without* it, `recArrAdd()` is called *255* times and *with* it *187* (input `[1,3,5,4,25,8,14]`).

---

Here follows your revised code and some sample outputs:

```
function arrayAddition(arr) {
    var arrMax = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
    var found = false;


    function recArrAdd(sub, arr) {
        if (found) return true;
        if (arr.length > 0) {
            var arrSum = sub.concat(arr[0]).reduce(function(prev, curr) { return prev + curr;});
            if (arrSum === arrMax){
                if (arr[0] != arrMax){
                    found = true;
                    return found;
                }
            };
            recArrAdd(sub.concat(arr[0]), arr.slice(1));
            recArrAdd(sub, arr.slice(1));
        }
        return found;
    }

    return recArrAdd([], arr);
}

console.log("[1,2,3] -> "+arrayAddition([1,2,3]));
console.log("[1,2,5] -> "+arrayAddition([1,2,5]));
console.log("[1,2,5,4,20,8] -> "+arrayAddition([1,2,5,4,20,8]));
console.log("[1,2,5,4,21,8] -> "+arrayAddition([1,2,5,4,21,8]));
console.log("[1,3,5,4,25,8,14] -> "+arrayAddition([1,3,5,4,25,8,14]));
console.log("[1,3,5,4,45,8,14] -> "+arrayAddition([1,3,5,4,45,8,14]));
```

which yields:

[image]

in Firefox using Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are bounded by 31 there exists beautiful solution:

Let `n` be the maximum and `arr` the rest of numbers. Then the following code checks what you want

```
var mask = 1;
for (var idx = 0; idx < arr.size; idx++) {
    mask = mask | mask << arr[idx];
}
return (mask >>> n) & 1;
```

It can be generalized for bigger restrictions using array of `boolean` instead of bit mask.

Some explanation. At the beginning mask is `00000001`, marking that by sums of empty set we can make 0 (as `1` is at position 0). Then on every step `mask` is mask for all sums we can make. Then by adding `arr[idx]` for each sum `s` we can make `s + arr[idx]`. So mask of new sums will be `mask << arr[idx]`. But we can still make all old sums of mask `mask`. So new value for mask is `mask | mask << arr[idx]`. In the end `mask` is mask for all possible sums and if `n` is possible sum then n-th bit (`(mask >>> n) & 1`) is `1` and `0` in either way.

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail? Are these >>> << bitshifters? How does it work?

Comment: Don't use `for ... in` for looping through arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```
function sumEqualsMax(values) {
    var maxValue = Math.max.apply(Math, values);
    var sumParts = values.slice();
    sumParts.splice(sumParts.indexOf(maxValue), 1);

    var sumValue = sumParts.reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue) {
        return previousValue + currentValue;
    }, 0);

    return sumValue === maxValue;
}

var values = [4, 6, 23, 10, 3];
console.log(sumEqualsMax(values));
```

Comment: It's supposed to return `true` when some combination of the values (not necessarily all of them) add up to the maximum value.

Comment: Ah, I see. Didn't get that from your question.